# Converting working code into a method, which will take dataframe columns values as input and would return 0 and 1 as values of a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods

I am new to core python. I have a working code which I need to convert into a method.
So, I have around 50k data with 30 columns. Out of 30 columns 3 columns are important for this requirement. `Id`,`Code`, and `bill_id`. I need to populate new column "multiple_instance" with 0s and 1s. Hence, final dataframe will contain 50k data with 31 columns. 'Code' column contains n number of codes, hence I am filtering my interest of codes and applying the remaining concept.
I need to pass these 3 columns in a method() which would return 0s and 1s.

Note: multiple_instance_codes is a variable which can be changed later.

````
multiple_instance_codes = ['A','B','C','D']
filt = df['Code'].str.contains('|'.join(multiple_instance_codes ), na=False,case=False)
df_mul = df[filt]
df_temp = df_mul.groupby(['Id'])[['Code']].size().reset_index(name='count')
df_mul = df_mul.merge(df_temp, on='Id', how='left')
df_mul['Cumulative_Sum'] = df_mul.groupby(['bill_id'])['count'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
df_mul['multiple_instance'] = np.where(df_mul['Cumulative_Sum'] > 1, 1, 0)```

**Sample data :**
bill_id     Id   Code       Cumulative_Sum   multiple_instance
10          1    B          1                0
10          2    A          2                1
10          3    C          3                1
10          4    A          4                1
````

Comment: What would be the expected output from your sample data?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by passing the columns to a method. Do you want to create a function that, given a dataframe df, will apply your code to it? Do you want to add the `multiple_instance` column to the original df?

Comment: Just adding `df['multiple_instance'] = df_mul['multiple_instance']` at the end of your code will add the `multiple_instance` column to the original df.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by passing the columns to a method. Do you want to create a function that, given a dataframe df, will apply your code to it? Do you want to add the multiple_instance column to the original df?   ................. YES.

Comment: @Massifox code column contains 'A' to 'Z' values. If multiple instances of A,B,C or D comes in a single bill then it should mark it as 1.

Comment: `def function_name(df):`, and then your code, indented. And remember to put the last line I suggested in my previous comment. You can also do `def function_name(df, multiple_instance_codes):`, so you can run it with different codes each time. [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). BTW, this is very basic python, you may want to check a couple of quick [tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, It is completed and working fine.
def multiple_instance(df):
df_scored = df.copy()
filt = df_scored['Code'].str.contains('|'.join(multiple_instance_codes), na=False,case=False)
df1 = df_scored[filt]
df_temp = df1.groupby(['Id'])[['Code']].size().reset_index(name='count')
df1 = df1.merge(df_temp, on='Id', how='left')
df1['Cum_sum'] = df1.groupby(['bill_id'])['count'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
df_scored = df_scored.merge(df1)
df_scored['muliple instance'] = np.where(df_scored['Cumulative_Sum'] > 1, 1, 0)
return df_scored

Comment: I don't know why I asked this question, when I can do it by my own. I am new to python and don't have this habit to put the code in a single method. Thanks @Ignatius Reilly